# Subtract Characters from Textview

Tags: swift, char, textview

I have a textView that acts as a user's bio. There's another feature of the app that shows a preview of the user's bio, but only a preview so the number of characters should be limited. For instance, I only want 30 characters out of the textview's total character count to be displayed. So I figured that Id implement shouldChangeTextIn:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    return newText.count < 30
}
```

Doesn't work though because it's not meant for this situation. This is fine if you want to limit the number of characters that are being inputted but not when reading data and displaying it in a text view.

**If I have a "bio" field stored in my database, and I call that information to be shown in a textView, how can show just the first 30 characters only, instead of displaying the entire field?**

Comment: You do not display data in a `UITextView`, you use a `UILabel` for that.

Comment: Whats wrong with using a text view? @RakeshaShastri

Comment: It is an element optimized for input, For displaying you have something optimized for output which is `UILabel`.

Comment: Oh ok I get it. So, how would I go about solving this problem but with using a label?

Comment: I am asking if you use the textView to actually change the data and then get the data from the textView when the user is done editing it and display it in a label?

Comment: I have the text being displayed in a text view, but I want to switch it to a label

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178407/discussion-between-vandal-and-rakesha-shastri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `UITextView` for getting the text and you have a `UILabel` to show the cropped bio info, this is how you should do it.

```
let limit = 30

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    label.text = String(textView.text.prefix(limit)) //define your limit outside or hard code it as you wish.
}
```

Or you could update it **live** using the other delegate.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    label.text = String(textView.text.prefix(limit))
}
```

Comment: Do not use `shouldChangeTextIn` for this. Use `textViewDidChange`.

Comment: @rmaddy yea my bad. Edited. The occasional brain fart. _sigh_

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the string when you assign it to the textView initially using String's prefix( maxLength:int) function.

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.isEditable = false
textView.text = String(bioFromDatabase.prefix(30))
```

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') to type 'String!'

Comment: It has to be casted to a String